# Обособляемое уточнение или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

> Проводником между главным героем и миром взрослых, между мечтой и
>   реальностью, оказывается девушка Ольга, которую играет Инга Ильм.

Запятая после "реальностью" нужна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если главный герой олицетворяет мечту, возможна и вторая запятая - как обособление пояснения, если нет - это однородные члены, после них запятая не ставится, только между ними:

*Проводником между главным героем и миром взрослых, между мечтой и реальностью оказывается девушка Ольга, которую играет Инга Ильм.*